# why my tcp server sends data twice, my tcp server is based on lwip raw api

Tags: tcp, server, lwip

here is my server:

```
void tcp_server_init(void)
{
    struct tcp_pcb* tpcb;

    tpcb = tcp_new();

    tcp_bind(tpcb, IP_ADDR_ANY, 13400);

    tpcb = tcp_listen(tpcb);

    tcp_accept(tpcb, tcp_server_accept);
}

static err_t tcp_server_callback(void* arg, struct tcp_pcb* tpcb, struct pbuf* recv_buf, err_t err);

static err_t tcp_server_accept(void* arg, struct tcp_pcb *tpcb, err_t err)

{

    tcp_recv(tpcb, tcp_server_callback);

    return ERR_OK;
}

static err_t tcp_server_callback(void* arg, struct tcp_pcb* tpcb, struct pbuf* recv_buf, err_t err)
{
    struct pbuf* tbuf;

    if(recv_buf != NULL)
    {
        tcp_recved(tpcb, recv_buf->tot_len);

        if(recv_buf->tot_len > BUFFER_SIZE)
        {
            memcpy(tbuf->data, recv_buf->payload, BUFFER_SIZE);
            tbuf->len = BUFFER_SIZE;
        }
        else
        {
            memcpy(tbuf->data, recv_buf->payload, recv_buf->tot_len);
            tbuf->len = recv_buf->tot_len;
        }
        tbuf->pcb = pcb;

        pbuf_free(recv_buf);
    }
}
```

I copy the recv data to the tbuf, and then process it in another app. I register a `Tcp_send` function in the app, and then send data through the function, here is the function:

```
void Tcp_send(void* pcb, const void* buf, uint16_t len) 
{
        struct tcp_pcb* tpcb =(struct tcp_pcb*) pcb;

        if(tpcb == NULL)
            return;

        tcp_write(tpcb,buf, len, 1);
        tcp_output(tpcb);
 }
```

it works, but sometimes the server sends the same data twice, which is not what I want.
Can anyone have the same problem or help me?

Comment: I have the same problem. What was the reason?